# How to make geom_path correspond to geom_beeswarm points

Tags: r, ggplot2, beeswarm

I've been trying to visualize the association of several characteristics in a small sample.

Here is an example data:

```
set.seed(309)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1:9, 5:9, 7:9),
           count=c(sample(1:4,9, prob=c(.5,.3,.2,.1), replace = T),
                   c(1,1,3,2,4), c(1,2,1)),
           strain=c(rep("A", 9), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 3)))
dat$feature <- (dat$id%%2==0)*1 + (dat$id%%2!=0)*0
dat$id <- as.factor(dat$id)
dat$feature <- factor(dat$feature, labels=c("X","Y"))
```

I tried it with `geom_point` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=strain, y=count,group=id))+ 
  geom_point(aes(col=feature), size=10, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  geom_path(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+  theme_minimal()
```

[example 1 with geom_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsFGf.png)

The problem is the points are overlapped no matter what `width` I have in the `position_dodge()`. `geom_beeswarm` produces a better looking plot:

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=strain, y=count,group=id))+ 
  geom_beeswarm(aes(col=feature), size=10, cex=6.5)+
  geom_path(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+  theme_minimal()
```

[example 2 with geom_beeswarm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Mh5.png)

But the connection with `geom_path` falls apart. The lines are supposed to connect the records with the same ID.

Is there a way to make `geom_path` correspond to `geom_beeswarm` points? Or, is there a way to tweak `geom_point` to have equally spaced points like `geom_beeswarm`?